# What are the most striking disagreements between Clement of Alexandria and Irenaeus?

Tags: church-fathers, clement-of-alexandria

What are the most striking disagreements (if any) between  Clement of Alexandria and Irenaeus?

The unanimity of the early Church Fathers is something that is often presented as an indisputable fact. However, while they were all in agreement about some major points of faith, there might have been some disagreements on some minor things. So, the question is about that.

Comment: You accidentally posted this question twice. Can you delete this one?

Comment: @MartinRosenau - One question is about the second century, the other one is about the third.

Comment: This is too broad - why not read a church history book on the period? Or you could edit it to ask specifically about two individuals.

Comment: @curiousdannii - Thank you for your advice. I didn't know it was too broad. I thought that reducing the time period to only one century would have made it narrow enough. I don't really know which two individuals to choose. I chose the first two names from the wiki page on Church fathers: Athanasius of Alexandria and Basil the Great (and will make the appropriate edits to incorporate these two names into my question). Do you think it's a good choice?

Comment: Yeah I think that's good.

Comment: You realize that Athanasius and Basil are from the 4th century, right?

Comment: @Nathaniel - Just changed to Clement of Alexandria and Irenaeus. Since now it's about two individuals, it shouldn't be precisely one specific century.

Comment: @brilliant I'm not sure the consensus of the Fathers *ever* referred to complete and absolute unanimity on every issue.

Comment: @SolaGratia - So my question attempts to find the biggest of the issues, on the matter of which there was no unanimity.